# Link For Portfolio Categories

Tags: categories, links

I am using portfolio posts to show products.
I've created 4 portfolio category. And placed my products under these categories.
My problem is it wont give links like blog posts.
When i am add a blog post it gives a link includes categories but not in portfolio posts.

**Current URL**: http://example.com/portfolio-item/product/

**Wanted URL:** http://example.com/category-name/product/

How can i make this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at permalinks structure ?

Comment: /%category%/%postname%  in pemalink settings